# boards.txt - how to create sub-menu (NOT new board!!!)

Tags: arduino-ide, ide, arduino-setup

Arduino 1.8.19

Is it possible to create a sub-menu inside `boards.txt` that would allow having the boards grouped for example by the manufacturer?
If it is possible, please provide an example or at least documentation for the language which is used for boards.txt.

I **don't** want to add a new board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The board menu ([defined here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/43b0818f7fa8073301db1b80ac832b7b7596b828/app/src/processing/app/Base.java#L1427)) is a single flat menu with "scroller" added to it.

To have multiple layers of menu you'd have to rewrite that entire part of the IDE.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is truly a great answer!